# How to make a like button with jquery inside a form so that it will save it to database and also change the style of like button?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am working on a django project and I want to add a like button to the posts.

Just like a regular like button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWH3.jpg)

this is my template:

```
 <form action="{% url 'like' post.id %}" method="GET" name="liked" class="l-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <button style="display: inline;" class="like__btn">
      <i class="like__icon fa fa-heart" style="display: inline;"></i> 
    </button>
</form>
   <script>
  $('.like__btn').on('click', function(){
$('.like__icon.fa-heart.fa').toggleClass("liked");
});
</script>
```

All I want to do this, when user clicks on a heart icon, it will submit the form. But also change the icon color to red. (*liked* class is basically, *color:red*)

When I click on the button it submits the form, increases the like count, but then it refreshes the page so my heart icon doesn't stay red.

If I add

```
 type="button"
```

this time it doesn't refresh the page, change the color of the icon but doesn't submit the form.

I tried to do another button to submit the form and make it hidden but whenever the form is submitted it refreshes the page and goes back to the white heart.

Also tried to return false; in jquery but it doesn't submit the form again.

I am stuck for hours, so any advice would be great! I am not sure if I should do it in a different way or it would work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @wmorrell, you need to submit an AJAX request. Here is a simplified example of how you can achieve that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var like_counter = 0;
  $(".like__btn").click(function() {
    like_counter++;
    var reference = this;
    var postpk = $(this).data('postpk');
    var userpk = $(this).data('userpk');
    $.ajax({
      url: "//",  #put your relevant url here
      data: {like_counter: like_counter},
      success: function(result) {
    $(reference).addClass("liked");
  },
      })
});
})
```

And in your html you have something like:

```
<a href="javascript:" class="like__btn" data-postpk="{{post_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Like</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do an AJAX request, so the "form" goes through the submit process, but there is no page load clearing out the current page state. This would involve setting a click handler on the button, which you already have. Then, in addition to setting the class on the button, use the JQuery [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) family of functions to simulate a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form using HTML it will refresh the page. One way around this is to submit the form using jQuery instead.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59

Keep in mind here that as soon as the user reloads or revisits the page, the heart will no longer be 'liked' and won't be shown as red.